# Getting a Timeout from AWS Lambda AmazonDynamoDBClient dbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am attempting to create an AmazonDynamoDBClient from a Java Lambda function on AWS.  I am getting a timeout error and cannot figure out why.  I create an SQSClient instance in the same lambda, successfully.

The init method of these are pretty similar.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your function works longer than default timeout for lambda function execution (3 seconds).
Trey increasing your timeout in **Configuration** -> **Advanced settings** -> **Timeout**